# Remove ability to Paypal to change address delivery

Tags: magento2, paypal

Using Magento 2, I have an addon who set delivery address. (click & collect). Sadly, if customer use Paypal, he overrides the delivery address.

I don't want Paypal changing delivery address.

Any idea how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try overdrive your particular PayPal model request class using preference by custom module and change address_override true to false

like on below file

> vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Hostedpro/Request.php

`'address_override' => 'true'` 
change to 
`'address_override' => 'false'`